# Cannot set height and width for UIButton on WebViews ScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, uibutton

I have a UIButton on a WebView's scroll view with type RoundRect. When I try to set its height it does not work.

I have tried with the following code:

```
CGRect  buttonFrame = CGRectMake(15.0, 89.0, 295.0, 40.0);
[btnHideStatus setBounds:buttonFrame];

[webView.scrollView addSubView:btnHideStatus];
```

Can someone explain why hieght and width is not changing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `setFrame :` method ??

```
[btnHideStatus setFrame:buttonFrame];
```